# Unexpected identifier error when import json file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Hi I am using node 16 for my project. When I deploy my app in Azure App Service. When I start running the application, I get the following error:

```
import myToken from './MyToken.json' assert {type: "json"};
                                      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:139:18)
ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:236:14)
```

Can anyone please help on it? Thank you

My node version v16.13.1. I deploy the nodejs to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

> Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature. This feature could
> change at any time

Try getting Node launched with `--experimental-json-modules`